# Facebook downloaded data does not contain Messenger images any more?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, download

I downloaded all my Facebook data some months ago, and in the 'messages' folder I had a folder named 'photos' containing every single picture in any of my conversations.

Just a few days ago my friend downloaded his data, and his package does not seem to contain any Messenger photos. There are more folders, but no photos folder in messages. Did Facebook remove Messenger photos from the downloadable data? Or does it have to be downloaded in some other way?

Comment: I have not heard any announcement from Facebook regarding this. So, you can test this downloading your data again to check if photo folder is there or not, if no one getting photo folder then possible they have stopped.